# How to get all <a> tags with the class "titular" with BeautifulSoup library?

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup

I have tried this [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA7VL.png), but even though they are more than one  tag with this class, I only get one element from the function.

Comment: Edit your question so it self-contained as a [mre].

Comment: Do not post sourcecode and data as images. Post these as part of your question as formatted text.

Comment: Oh and when browsing that page with javascript turned off, Chrome says there's only one `a` element with class `titular`. `requests` does not execute javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A large portion (actually, most of) the page is rendered in JavaScript, which is evident by the (relatively) long waiting time until the articles are loaded. The `requests` module doesn't execute JavaScript, so there will only be one `a.titular` element. You could use `selenium`, which waits for the JavaScript to render, then pass the page source to `bs4.BeautifulSoup()`.

```py
>>> import bs4
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> browser.get("https://elperuano.pe/")
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_content, features="html.parser")
>>> len(soup.select("a.titular"))
29
```

You'll have to install `selenium`: `$ pip install selenium`.

FYI: The `a.titular` selector is equivalent to the `a[class='titular']` selector, which selects all `<a class="titular">` elements. (Refer to [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for a list of CSS selectors.)